# Bash command execution output in IntelliJ or AndroidStudio breaks single line output to multiple

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Lets say I have a bash script that outputs percentage execution in a single line as follows:

```
Installing: 10%
```

where the number goes from 0 to 100 in the same line. Now if I use the "Edit Configuration" option in the IDE to create a shortcut to execute the same script (see screenshot below), the output in the IDE console looks like this:

```
Installing: 0%
Installing: 1%
.
.
Installing: 99%
Installing: 100%
```

all in separate lines. Since the script works well on a standard console, I am guessing this is a problem with the Run console? Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can't fix it, IntelliJ IDEA Run console is not a real terminal.

Comment: :( Surely there is some code that interprets line ends incorrectly. Since the community edition is open source, it would be great to find out the bug. I will spend sometime digging up but would appreciate any tips.